# Passing where clause with range that will prompt user in arcpy.select_analysis?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, where-clause

I am trying to query the user to enter a price range so that all those which are in his range will be retrieved.

```
choice = input("Enter the budget range:")
arcpy.Select_analysis("Zillow_Project.shp", "Budget", "'[Price]' in choice" )
```

The price value should be a range like (startvalue , endvalue) which will be given by the option choice.

Comment: I would use 2 input parameters: range's lowest value and range's highest value. Then use these 2 values in a sql clause in Select (e.g. [Price] > MinValue AND [Price] < MaxValue).

Comment: For example assume min value = choice 1 and max value = choice 2 ..Then how do we use the query  arcpy.Select_analysis("Zillow_Project.shp", "Budget", '[Price]'>choice1 and '[Price]'<choice2 )    choice 1 and choice 2 are the prompts given to user

Comment: Should the user be able to type the min and max values, or should he pick the values from a list of predefined values? And how are you going to use this: in a script tool, in the commande line, ...?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo.. 1 and 2 are the right ones. how does the query look?       arcpy.Select_analysis("Zillow_Project.shp", "Budget", '[Price]'>choice1 and '[Price]'<choice2 ) . This is not working for me

Answer (score 1):

So your script should look like this:

```
Min = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Max = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

field = "Price"
field_del = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters("Zillow_Project.shp", field)
where = """{0} > {1} AND {0} < {2}""".format(field_del, Min, Max)

arcpy.Select_analysis("Zillow_Project.shp", "Budget", where)
```

If you want the user to enter the min and max values as 1 parameter, you can try this:

```
Range = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Min = Range.split(",")[0]
Max = Range.split(",")[1]
## assuming the min and max values are separated by a comma

field = "Price"
field_del = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters("Zillow_Project.shp", field)
where = """{0} > {1} AND {0} < {2}""".format(field_del, Min, Max)

arcpy.Select_analysis("Zillow_Project.shp", "Budget", where)
```

Nevertheless I wouldn't use this option which is more prone to errors, eg. if the user adds a space after the comma it won't work. You can of course trim the spaces and add other error-catching code, but having 2 separate parameters should just prevent this from happening.

Comment: Its throwing me the following error:

Comment: arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression Price >  AND Price < 
Failed to execute (Select).

Comment: Im using ArcGIS Pro 1.1 and running the script in Pycharm (3.4.1 is the interpreter)

Comment: You have to provide values for Min and Max! `arcpy.GetParameterAsText()` expects some user input

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to prompt the user to give input. So I should write like min = input () and max = input() .. Now I should try to insert them in my query

Comment: I think this should work, but its throwing me an error

Comment: Min = input("Enter the minimum budget range:")
Max = input("Enter the maximum budget range: ")

Min = (arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0))
Max = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

where = """Price > {0} AND Price < {1}""".format(Min, Max)

arcpy.Select_analysis("Zillow_Project.shp", "Budget", where)

Comment: I liked your first approach but I want to know if first we will be prompting the user to enter min and max values and then over write with those that you mentioned in the script??

Comment: Its not at all working, by using either of the methods.. Please let me know how should i approach.

Comment: I don't use PyCharm and I don't know how you enter dynamic parameters before running the script. You should not modify the code, just somehow type the values (min and max) the script needs to run.

Comment: I dont understand where the logic is missing actually.